# how to recuperate the value of the chosen option in checkbox with laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5.3

I try to save the value of the chosen option of ckeckbox in database.
but I get always the value "on" saved in my database even I did not chose any option.
 this is the code of answercontroller .

```
 public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey) 
  {

    // remove the token
    $arr = $request->except('_token');
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      $newAnswer = new Answer();
      if (! is_array( $value )) {
        $newValue = $value['answer'];
      } else {
        $newValue = json_encode($value['answer']);
      }

      $newAnswer->answer = $newValue;
      $newAnswer->question_id = $key;
      $newAnswer->user_id = Auth::id();
      $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;

      $newAnswer->save();

    };
```

this is the view:

```
 {!! Form::open() !!}
                        @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                          {{ Form::text('title')}}
                        @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                            <label for="textarea1">Provide answer</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')

                          @foreach((array)$question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                            <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                              <input type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" name="answer"/>
                              <label for="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                            </p>
                          @endforeach
                        @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')

                          @foreach((array)$question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                          <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $key }}" />
                            <label for="{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                          </p>
                          @endforeach
```

please help me , how can i get the value of the option. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not setting the value and name of checkbox

```
@foreach((array)$question->option_name as $key=>$value)
    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $key }}" value="{{ $value }}" name="mycheck[]" />
    <label for="{{$key}}">{{ $value }}</label>
    </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please accept Answer, so that others can take help from it as well, Thanks